# Calling goto on a wide-char string in C (GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, binary, goto, opcode

I found this piece of code:

```
goto*&L"\xfeeb";
```

It causes the program to hang forever, apparently through calling the x64 instructions `0xEB` and `0xFE` (in that order, due to x64's little-endianness). `0xEB` is JMP according to the [x86 Opcode and Instruction Reference](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html).

I understand what the code *does*, and that it is equivalent to a function running the instructions `0xEB 0xFE`, so it can also be written as `int (*foo)() = L"\xfeeb"; foo();`, or if we wanted to get really obfuscated, `((int(*)())L"\xfeeb")();`. This is due to the fact that strings are marked executable by default on Linux.

However, `goto` is really strict. I don't understand why `goto*&L"\xfeeb";` works at all, or what the crazy pointer magic `*&` is doing, or why the wide mark `L` is necessary. Can someone explain?

Comment: If you want to try all these obfuscated snippets without compiling them individually yourself, you can use an online C compiler: [`goto*&L"\xfeeb";`](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8zr0QhNzEzT6MsPzNFk6uaSwEI0vNL8rXUfJRiKtJSU5OUrLlq//8HAA) and [`int (*foo)() = L"\xfeeb"; foo();`](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8zr0QhNzEzT6MsPzNFk6uaSwEIQIIaWmn5@Zoamgq2Cj5KMRVpqalJStZgWaC4hqY1V@3//wA) and [`((int(*)())L"\xfeeb")();`](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8zr0QhNzEzT6MsPzNFk6uaSwEINDSAwhpamhqamj5KMRVpqalJSkCONVft//8A)

Comment: Just a GCC [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35236834/5267751) ([docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html)). [Clang](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///PzOvRCE3MTNPoyw/M0WTq5pLAQjS80vytdR8lGIq0lJTk5SsuWr//wcA) doesn't support that.

Comment: @user202729 still don't understand what part of GCC decided to allow that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to hazard a guess, the person who wrote the code was abusing [GCC's Labels as Values extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html). This feature was intended to make jump tables or portable JIT compilers or other things for which `switch...case` would be too slow.

C lets you `goto` a label.

```
label1:
...
goto label1;
```

GCC lets you take the address of a label with the `&&` operator. To jump to an address `foo` you can just `goto *foo;`.

```
label1:
void *ptr = &&label1;
...
goto *ptr;
```

Just to recap, the C standard specifies that the argument following the `goto` statement be a token of type *label*. GCC adds an extension where the argument following the `goto` statement may also be a *pointer to a pointer to executable code*.

Therefore you can `goto` any piece of memory for which you have a pointer. On Linux, this includes string literals.

```
goto *&"\xe8\r\0\0\0Hello, World!Yj\1[j\rZj\4X\xcd\x80,\f\xcd\x80";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8zr0QhNzEzT0OzmktBIT2/JF9LTSmmItUipijGAAQ9UnNy8nUUwvOLclIUI7NiDKOzYoqismJMImIqklNiKiwMdGLSYEwla67a//8B)

`L"\xfeeb"` is a *wide string literal* composed of characters of type `wchar_t` instead of `char`. Written as an old fashioned string literal, it would be `"\xeb\xfe"`. I suspect the `L` in your string literal was serving the purpose of a [MacGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin).

Comment: "the person who wrote the code" [ಠ_ಠ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104999/61563)

Comment: The gcc extension permits `goto *foo;` where `foo` is of type `void*`. Due to a bug, it seems to allow `foo` to be of pointer types other than `void*`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35236834/827263) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35237062/827263).